# how to properly insert/update a nested mongodb document using node/express app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack, meanjs

In my NodeJS/Express app, I have a MongoDB collection "SalesforceData", in which every document has the following structure:
The master record has two fields - OpportunityId and OpportunityName.
Each master record has an array of nested DataCenter records:

```
{
    OpportunityId: '',  
    OpportunityName: '',
    DataCenters: [
         { DataCenterName:'', address:'' },
         { DataCenterName:'', address:'' }
    ]
}
```

Initially, the Data Center fields were part of the actual Opportunity record. but now, we have a one-to-many between a single opportunity and many data centers.

The following code was working fine for a single record update:

```
app.post('/salesforce_update', function(req, res){
        console.log('Salesforce update Request Received');
        console.log('request body:  ' + req.body);

        MongoClient.connect(url, function (err, db) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Unable to connect to the mongoDB server. Error:', err);
            } else {
                var collection = db.collection('SalesforceData');
                collection.update(
                    {
                        CSCOpportunityID:  req.body.opportunityId
                    },
                    {$set:
                    {
                        kwFY16: req.body.kwRequired_2016,
                        kwFY17: req.body.kwRequired_2017,
                        kwFY18: req.body.kwRequired_2018,
                        kwFY19: req.body.kwRequired_2019,
                        kwFY20: req.body.kwRequired_2020,
                        kwFY21: req.body.kwRequired_2021,
                        kwFY22: req.body.kwRequired_2022,
                        kwFY23: req.body.kwRequired_2023,
                        kwFY24: req.body.kwRequired_2024,
                        kwFY25: req.body.kwRequired_2025,

                        cbFY16: req.body.cbRequired_2016,
                        cbFY17: req.body.cbRequired_2017,
                        cbFY18: req.body.cbRequired_2018,
                        cbFY19: req.body.cbRequired_2019,
                        cbFY20: req.body.cbRequired_2020,
                        cbFY21: req.body.cbRequired_2021,
                        cbFY22: req.body.cbRequired_2022,
                        cbFY23: req.body.cbRequired_2023,
                        cbFY24: req.body.cbRequired_2024,
                        cbFY25: req.body.cbRequired_2025,

                        DCCountry: req.body.dcCountry,
                        DCSiteCode: req.body.dcSiteCode,
                        DCSKU: req.body.dcSku
                    }

                    },
                        {upsert:true},
                    function(err, result){
                    if(err){
                        console.log('err:  ' + err);
                    }
                        else{
                        console.log('update result:  ' + result);
                        res.send(201);
                    }
                });
            }
```

How could I modify this code to allow for inserts/updates of Data Center sub-records?

The unique combination of an opportunity and a data center would be OpportunityId along with DataCenterName.

Answer (score 0):

by doing some trial and error, I ended up with a solution, in which I first determine whether a given sub-document is present in the main document's array of sub-documents.
Then, depending on the result, I either add a new sub-document to that array, or update an existing one.

Here is the complete gist:  https://gist.github.com/eugene-goldberg/ee694ee7ee6121fbec46